# Нужна помощь в регулярном выражении для обратной польской нотации

Tags: регулярные-выражения

**Здравствуйте, друзья!**

У меня большие проблемы в понимании регулярных выражений. Я смотрел, читал, ну вот что-то не идет совсем, пишу уже от безысходности.

Есть запись выражения вида обратной польской нотации: `3 5 * 4 / 55 2 * - 10 +`. Нужно составить регулярку. между каждым символом пробел. Единственное что получилось у меня

```
(([\d]{1,10}|[+\-*\/])\s){1,100}
```

Правда, оно не до конца правильно, так как первые значения в выражении должны быть точно цифрами, а не знаками, а последнее значение точно знаком, что в моей регулярке не выполняется. Я пытался это исправить используя якоря $ и ^, но мне не удается сделать так чтобы были фиксированные элементы вначале и конце строки, а посередине любой длины выражении вида символ/число + пробел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\s*(\d+\s+){2}((\d+|[-+*\/])\s+)*[-+*\/]\s*$
```

- `^` - начало строки
- `\s*` - необязательные пробелы (просто игнорируем)
- `(\d+\s+){2}` - число, и затем пробел (повторяются два раза)
- `((\d+|[-+*\/])\s+)*` число или знак из набора, и затем пробел (могут повторяться сколько угодно раз, или не быть вовсе)
- `[-+*\/]` - знак из набора
- `\s*` - необязательные пробелы (просто игнорируем)
- `$` - конец строки